# MS AccessのVBAでExcelにテーブルをエクスポートするときに、テーブルとして書式設定する方法

Tags: excel, ms-access

MS Access 2019を使用しています。

AccessからExcelにデータをVBAコードからエクスポートする方法は当たり前のようにできるのですが、
出力したExcelファイルのデータを『テーブルとして書式設定』した状態で出力したいのですが、
エクスポートするときにまとめてできる方法はありますでしょうか。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

そもそも、Excelのテーブルの機能は新しいバージョンからのものでしかできないため、
仮にあったとしても、Access側のVBAも新しいものしか対応していないとは思いますが、
もしあるのでしたら、その方法を教えていただけますでしょうか。

現在だと、一度エクスポートして出力し、もう一度そのExcelファイルを読み込んで
ワークシートオブジェクトに変更を加えるといったことをしなければならないようなので、
エクスポートする時点でテーブルの書式設定ができるのが良いと思っています。

よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: AccessがExcelへエクスポートするのではなく、ExcelがAccessからインポートすることをお勧めします。

Comment: 残念ですが、それは全体のシステムからできません。EXcelはあくまでも出力されたファイルとしてしか扱わないため、そこからまたほかのものを読み込むことはさせません。もし、その方法でしかできないのだとしたら、結果『できない』ということなのでしょうか。

Comment: 「できない」は悪魔の証明なので回答が付きづらいと思います。

Comment: @たたぱた ここでの「できない」は「技術的に不可能」なのか「運用の選択肢として採用したくない」のどちらなのかはっきりさせた方が良いと思います。

Comment: 申し上げているように、二度手間をすることなく、メソッドレベルでエクスポートの時に指定できるような方法はあるか…ということです。…そう本文にも書いてあるはずですが。すみませんが、質問には『回答』でお答えいただけますよう、お願いいたします。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

やはり現時点では対応策はないようですので、この質問はここで終了いたします。

Answer (score 0):

以下リンク先の手順が参考になるかもしれません。

[Excel にデータをエクスポートする - Access](https://support.microsoft.com/ja-jp/office/excel-%E3%81%AB%E3%83%87%E3%83%BC%E3%82%BF%E3%82%92%E3%82%A8%E3%82%AF%E3%82%B9%E3%83%9D%E3%83%BC%E3%83%88%E3%81%99%E3%82%8B-64e974e6-ae43-4301-a53e-20463655b1a9)

> ### エクスポートを実行する
>
> 6. テーブルまたはクエリをエクスポートしており、書式設定付きのデータをエクスポートしたい場合は、[**書式設定とレイアウトを保持したままデータをエクスポートする**] をオンにします。

---

**追記**

エクセルの「テーブルとして書式設定」ですが、これはデータの範囲や見出し、合計行などを設定するためのものであり、見た目のスタイルやデザインを引き継ごうとしているなら、使い方が間違っている可能性があります。

[「テーブルとして書式設定」が必要な場面](https://news.mynavi.jp/article/excelanalytics-19/)

> この機能の役割を「表の見た目を手軽に整えるもの」と理解している方もいるようだが、それは大きな間違いである。「テーブルとして書式設定」はデータの範囲を明確にするものであり、並べ替えなどを行う際にも役立つ機能となる。

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。いつも助かります。この項目も試してみたのですが、望んだとおりの結果にはなりませんでした。一つ一つのセルにはそれらしい設定がされて出力されているようですが、表全体には適用がないようです。

Comment: 何度もありがとうございます。おっしゃる通り、求めているものはデザインではなく、『テーブル』としての『機能』です。デザインは特に求めていません。それでいながら、やはり『テーブル』にはなっていなかったということです。